# I have a function which returns nodes in terms of latitude and longitudes using hibernate and spring. How do I map these nodes into a map using JUNG?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jung

I have a function which returns desired nodes from a tree in terms of latitude and longitudes( its values are real latitude and longitudes)  and I want to check the function by plotting them on a graph to make a map. How do I do so?
I was trying to use JUNG and create a map or graph through it but am finding it difficult to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that this has anything to do with JUNG (the connections between the nodes seem irrelevant) but the JUNG sample [WorldMapGraphDemo](http://jung.sourceforge.net/site/apidocs/edu/uci/ics/jung/samples/WorldMapGraphDemo.html) gives an example of what you're asking for.

Comment: Can the connection between the nodes define a path ?

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You know what your data are and how you want to interpret and use them, I don't.  Have you tried looking at the sample?